# bash script pass enter [return] key to another script initiated through ssh heredoc

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I've run into an issue with a script I'm creating. It copies some data over to another server and then connecting to the server using an ssh heredoc it starts a second script located on the second server inside the heredoc.

The issue I've run into is that if you execute this second script through the bash script (as opposed to manually starting it) then it will skip a crucial step where the second script asks you to hit [enter] and then type in a password to generate some files.

[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlfo9.png)

[password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IpJi.png)

I don't have access to this second script so I can't change anything. I've tried all types of echo | ./script2.sh combos, printf, heredoc, and nothing works. Edit: expect is not available on this second server.

example of what I'm doing:

```
scp -r $dir xxxx@xxx.xx.x.xx:/as/df/qwerty/

ssh xxxx@xxx.xx.x.xx "bash -s" << EOF
# install
/as/df/qwerty/${choice}/./install_${choice}
EOF
```

Comment: Sounds like the second script expects a terminal. Maybe you can get around it with the "expect" program, which is created for scripting interactive applications.

Comment: I wish I could use expect but the second server doesn't have it and I don't have access to install it on that server either

Comment: If you've got enough access to run it through an interpreter you select, you've got enough access to modify how it runs -- you just might need to get a little bit... *creative*. For instance, if it's running `[ -t 0 ]` to check if stdin is a TTY, you can source the script into a shell that overrides `[` to do your own logic when `$1` is `-t` and `$2` is `0`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how do you propose I send the [enter] keystroke to this second script initiated within the ssh heredoc? Your reply seems like a foreign language to me as I'm new to bash, sorry.

Comment: Basically, I'm not proposing that you do. I'm proposing you read the source to the second script, figure out what it's doing around the place where it's currently trying to read from a TTY, and spoof that logic do something that makes more sense (for instance, unconditionally reading from stdin even in the non-TTY case). Is this script something that's publicly available, so I could look at it and offer a more concrete suggestion?

Comment: In general, btw, folks who are competent don't write scripts that have functionality only accessible with a TTY at hand. There's a very good chance that once you dig into the contents of your script, you'll find a built-in mechanism to enter your password through the environment or some other out-of-band process instead.

Comment: Do you know what the thing that's asking for a password actually is?  Is it `sudo` on the remote server? Some other application that maintains its own access control? This really sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry I can't paste most of the script here but I was able to take a look at it and it's essentially a script that calls even more shell scripts to build some files. Any attempt to echo | ./script2.sh or similar command in the script2's directory doesn't work. Can't seem to pipe anything to this second script, maybe that tells you something?

Comment: No, "doesn't work" doesn't tell me anything. I'd need to see the actual scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with `bash -s`, the shell is reading commands from standard input and the remote script is also reading from standard input.

Instead of passing the script as standard input to the shell, you could have the remote bash `source` a dynamically generated script from a heredoc, like:

```
ssh foo@bar "bash -c 'source <(cat <<EOF
/invoke/your/script.sh
EOF
)'"
```

Comment: I'm not trying to pass any script to the second server, rather I'm copying over a directory to this second server and then ssh into this second server to launch another script to build some files. The issue is this second script requires the user to press enter and then enter in a password to finish the install. I can't seem to script that [enter] keystroke and then the password. invoking the second script via the first script will skip that step entirely. sorry if I'm not explaining it well I'm new to bash

Comment: You're not actually avoiding quoting problems there. If your script uses, say, `$''`-style quoting, that *won't work* inside single-quotes, as you're trying to pass everything. Moreover, any single-quotes inside the script will close the single-quotes that you're injecting outside it.

Comment: If you want to quote a script to be safely interpreted by a remote shell, instead of wrapping `''`s around it (which, as mentioned before, *doesn't actually work* in the general case), use `printf '%q'` to generate an `eval`-safe version. Though that has its own pitfalls, if the `/bin/sh` on the remote system doesn't support the escaping forms that your shell's `%q` does, which is why `bash -s` and feeding the script on stdin is actually the preferred approach for this kind of scenario.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're totally right about single quotes, I'll remove mention of this being a good quote-preservation mechanism from my answer.